# Calculating the Hue of a Color as a 0 - 255 range

Tags: wpf, math, colors

I am trying to write a method which will work on WPF's `Color` struct to return a byte representing the Hue of the `Color`.  I am struggling with the formula, I have written unit tests for the hues of Black (255, 255, 255), Red (255, 0, 0), Green (0, 255, 0), Blue (0, 0, 255), Yellow (255, 255, 0), Cyan (0, 255, 255), Magenta (255, 0, 255) and White (255, 255, 255) - they all pass except Yellow (which returns 1 instead of 42) and Magenta (which tries to return -1 instead of 212 but fails as -1 won't cast into a byte).

My extension methods for `GetHue` appear as follows:

```
public static byte GetHue(this Color color)
    => GetHue(color.ToRgbDictionary(), color.GetMinComponent(), color.GetMaxComponent());

private static byte GetHue(Dictionary<ColorComponent, byte> rgbDictionary, ColorComponent minimumRgbComponent, ColorComponent maximumRgbComponent)
{
    decimal chroma = rgbDictionary[maximumRgbComponent] - rgbDictionary[minimumRgbComponent];

    return (byte)
    (
        chroma == 0
        ? 0
        : thirdOfByte
        * (byte)maximumRgbComponent
        +
        (
            rgbDictionary[MathHelper.Wrap(maximumRgbComponent + 1)]
            - rgbDictionary[MathHelper.Wrap(maximumRgbComponent - 1)]
        )
        / chroma
    );
}
```

`ToRgbDictionary` simply turns the `Color` into a dictionary of its red, green and blue components; `ColorComponent` is an enum used as the key for those components.  `MathHelper.Wrap` is a method which wraps an enum back into its declared range if it overflows or underflows.  `GetMinComponent` and `GetMaxComponent` are two other extension methods on `Color` which return the first lowest and first highest `ColorComponent`s of the `Color` (where the `ColorComponent` order is: Red, Green, Blue).  `thirdOfByte` is a constant equal to the `byte.MaxValue / 3`.

I have based this formula on another I found here (http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/rgbhsl_2.aspx) which looks like this:

```
private decimal GetH(RGB rgb, decimal max, decimal chroma)
{
    decimal h;
    if (rgb.R == max)
        h = ((rgb.G - rgb.B) / chroma);
    else if (rgb.G == max)
        h = ((rgb.B - rgb.R) / chroma) + 2M;
    else
        h = ((rgb.R - rgb.G) / chroma) + 4M;
    return 60M * ((h + 6M) % 6M);
}
```

The problem with that formula is it's mapped to a 0 - 360 hue range, not a 0 - 255 range which is what I need.  I'm not sure what the constant numbers in this formula do but I'm guessing the 60 has something to do with 360 / 3 = 120 hence my third of byte constant to try to do something similar.  As for the 6Ms I have no idea where they come from nor why they are added to and modulused with the hue value at that stage.  Could anyone with a mind for maths help me out here?

**UPDATE**
The reason for the 0 - 255 range was that I thought that was all that was required having seen it used in another piece of software (as shown) for Hue, Saturation and Lightness.  It is also where I obtained the 42 Hue value for Yellow.  I am now trying to find the correct range for Hues to cover all possible different hues in a 16777216 (256 * 256 * 256) colour range.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Your *"...except Yellow (which returns 1 instead of 42)"* what's the logic behind expecting a 42?
- It's *"mapped to a 0 - 360 hue range"* because there are 360 hues in the colour wheel. Even if you had an unsigned byte (holding 256 values), you'd be cropping off the other 104 possible hues. It won't be an accurate representation.
- Why not just use a 2-byte [**short**](https://www.dotnetperls.com/short) to hold the possible 360 hues instead of using 1 byte?

If you still want to fit 360 inside a 255 range, just do simple math :

```
byte_value = hue_value / (360/255); //where hue_value is the 0-360 amount.
```

Try involving [**Math methods**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) like `Math.round` to get none fractions as final  byte value.

Example 180 hue :

```
byte_value = Math.round( 180 / (360/255) ); //gives 127
```

Comment: I'm reconsidering using 0 - 255 now that you've said that; I do not wish to lose value resolution for the sake of saving 1 byte!  That means I could copy the formula now but I would still like to understand it (what's the significance of 60M, the two 6Ms, the 4M and the 2M).  I assume modulus as decimals is important due to the subsequent multiplication (after which rounding could be applied).

Comment: Just to clarify, is 360 the total number of possible Hues for 255 * 255 * 255 colours or just a way of mapping those Hues into a 1-hue-per-degree circle?  I'm after accuracy over coupling hues to the shape of a particular user control.